# May old questions be repeated for new version of language standard?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, language-versions

This question is based on the following case:

Recently, a [question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76867659/does-the-definition-int-a-0-b-a-c-a-have-defined-behavior-in-c) which is clearly a duplicate of an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431412/does-the-comma-in-a-declaration-for-multiple-objects-introduce-a-sequence-point).

The new question was quickly closed as a duplicate, however, the answers to the old question were applicable only for the C Standard version at that time, C11, and it became clear that the key clauses had been changed in C17 such that these answers were not valid for the new version of the Standard. Thus, the new question was re-opened (and an explanation and link to the older question added).

The new question was then answered in terms of the new standard version.

After that, a newcomer to the discussion flagged the question for moderation as a duplicate. That request was rejected.

There was clearly great doubt as to whether or not this should be a duplicate or not. **Thus the question here is: is there, or can we define, some guidelines to when it is appropriate to repeat an old question due to outdated answers?**

My preliminary thought on this is that repeating old questions should be an exception rather than the rule.

In this case, I think it was definitely useful. With the current functionality of SO, I doubt it would be possible to gather the necessary attention to create new answers in the old question and there would be no way to "accept" an answer for the new version.

On the other hand, I do not think it would be useful to encourage a wave of repeated questions to confirm whether or not the original answer is still valid.

From a user perspective I am in doubt if it would be more useful to have (a) a single question being updated with new answers or have (b) new questions with updated answers. In either case, I definitely do not think that old (correct) answers should be removed or "unaccepted". They would be still be relevant for people working under the old standard (e.g. maintenance projects).

I think case (a) would require new functions on the site to request and accept updated answers to an existing question which could then end up having more than one accepted answer. Case (b) is easier to handle with the current functionality, but should be governed by some strict guidelines for when it is appropriate to re-raise an existing question.

Comment: They already exist. Questions are duplicates when one answer precisely answers both of them. Simple. Just don't have the illusion that curation will never go wrong because such guidelines exist, humans will be humans. In a hurry.

Comment: @Gimby. That makes sense and I like the simplicity of this rule. Of course, errors are made, but it is easier to navigate when there are some clear-cut rules.  So this means that it is ok to repeat an existing question as long as the poster explains how the sought *answer* differs from the original one.

Comment: @nielsen: *So this means that it is ok to repeat an existing question as long as the poster explains how the sought answer differs from the original one.* This was my reasoning and I modified the question with references to previously asked questions along with an explanation as to why none of the answers were adequate nor sufficiently documented.

Comment: For this the relevant thing would be the old discussion about "outdated answers" which however as far as I know didn't really go somewhere except for the removal of the pinning effect of the acceptance mark and a new sort order (trending). Naming the versions in the answers is a good start however.

Comment: @chqrlie I agree with this reasoning. It seems to me that getting there was based on some good common sense decisions by experienced users. I am a big fan of that, but rules are easier to explain and defend. In this case, it was probably just me who was not aware of "the rule of Gimby :-)" and, admittedly, I was slightly provoked by the way it was challenged.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are expecting here – assuming these actually *are* duplicates then they should be closed as such. Even for the point of there being new answers, no-one is helped by having the version-specific information *intransparently scattered* across multiple questions. For attention there's bounties, and acceptance is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I was looking for consensus for a clear definition of duplicate. I personally like the rule stated by Gimby and the logic implication which I commented. Of course "duplicates" must be closed, but due to passing of time or implicit expectations, identically phrased *questions* could be looking for different *answers*. If there is not consensus about going for e.g. case (a) or (b) which I mention. If I understand correctly, you say it is clearly (a) and Gimby says equally clearly (b). Hence, I think this question is relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tag wiki for [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) (and C++) already states the guide lines:

> Unless the question explicitly mentions which version of the C standard that is used, it is assumed that the current version is used. That is, whichever version of ISO 9899 that ISO currently lists as active.

This is generally the stance for most major programming language tags on SO that have a formal definition or standard describing the language. Meaning as of today, always assume "C17" ISO 9899:2018 (soon to be :2023 or :2024) and old answers might not be up to date with C17.

Therefore when voting to close a duplicate tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) , the following needs to be considered:

- Is the contents of the question related to something which has been changed since the time when the duplicate target was posted? If you don't know for sure, refrain from casting close votes.
- Is the duplicate target generally up to date with the C standard or best practices?
- Is the duplicate target really a good one? Does it contain references, examples and so on? Or is there a chance that if we leave the question open even though it is a duplicate, a better answer might surface?

  If so don't close but re-visit later - maybe the old question should be closed as duplicate to the new one? When handling duplicates we don't care about post age or poster rep - only post quality and technical correctness matter.
- Please also ensure that the duplicate target isn't actually a C++ question, because that is often unfortunate, given how much subtle crap that makes C and C++ ever so slightly different.

---

This particular question was very hard to moderate since it stumped multiple C gurus (sorry, I might be to blame for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76867092/584518)) and although the [duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39431962/584518) was of high quality, it pre-dated C17. After researching this further personally I found out there had been changes in C17, there were DR and technical papers by the ISO C WG regarding this issue. And so not at all trivial to answer, neither out of a C11 or C17 perspective and I personally stepped away from attempting to answer at that point, since it would involve studying all of these papers in addition to C17.

These kind of questions should probably never be closed as dupes unless we can get several C gold badgers to agree in comments that it is indeed a dupe. Also before close-voting, consider that the poster had already done lots of research work and have a gold badge themselves.

Comment: Except for the last bullet (which only happens in C/C++ land), this is sensible advice for any language.

Comment: Re _"Also before close-voting, consider that the poster ... have a gold badge themselves."_, why is that of any relevance at all? Surely the evaluation of whether a question should be closed should be based _solely on its content_. The reputation of the author should be completely irrelevant. I don't mean any disrespect towards that specific author with a gold badge at all, but my larger concern is that you suggest that the author's reputation should be considered.

Comment: @skomisa Gold badge and reputation are two different and quite non-related things. The gold badge is the least bad way we have to determine someone's domain knowledge. Moderating this post was very difficult and the vast majority of users should just back off, including most gold badgers as well. I have a C gold badge but refrained from moderating this post since the technical details were too intricate to grasp at a glance and dismissing it as a duplicate was pre-mature.

Answer (score 3):

In general:
**It’s a duplicate**.
Stack Overflow’s mission is to [build a shared repository of knowledge](/help/non-english-questions) (not an archive).
There is a strong element of collaboration:
You may edit (at *any* time) other people’s questions and answers.
Sometimes knowledge becomes outdated.
You are certainly encouraged to edit answers accommodating for changes.
Some of the most active contributors already regularly update (primarily their own) answers (= housekeeping).

---

**Procedure**:
My suggestion is to *edit* the old (already answered) question so it includes a *version constraint*.
Restrictive version constraints are best practice of software documentation anyway.
Thus

> How do I make Foo produce Bar?

becomes

> How do I make Foo version 123 produce Bar?

By doing that the new question is not a duplicate anymore.
It can easily *attract* new answers in the Stack Overflow ecosystem.
The new answers accounting for the language changes can be *accepted*.

Comment: (Single newlines do not render here. Is there an intent?)